# How to get current NSDate in current timezone?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I need to get current time in NSDate, not swift. I tried to do this like on screenshot, but the final nsdate is in wrong timezone.[image]

Comment: An image of code for debugging is almost as useful as an image of food when you're hungry... *Include your code*, not an image of your code. You can use the [edit] button to fix your question.

Comment: Search for "NSDate IS AN ABSOLUTE POINT IN TIME AND HAS NO TIMEZONE" ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An `NSDate` does not have a time zone. It records an instant in time on planet Earth. It is DISPLAYED in a particular time zone.

An `NSDateFormatter` will convert between NSDate objects and date strings (in either direction).

If you install a time zone into your date formatter then it will convert dates to/from strings using that time zone. If you don't specify a time zone it will use the user's current time zone.

If you try to display an NSDate using the Swift `print` statement or `NSLog` then it will be *displayed* in UTC. Always.

The code you've posted that prints strDate, your date string you created using a date formatter, is correct. The line `print(localDate!) is meaningless.

To repeat: `NSDate` objects do not have a time zone. When you log them to the console, they will always be displayed in UTC. If you want to see them in your local time zone then you need to use date formatter like you are doing.

Comment: ... and that has been asked and answered so often ...